# Is it possible to have in Apache 2.4 different NamedVirtualHost, each with its own SSLProtocol ? I am using SSLStrictSNIVHostCheck

Tags: apache-http-server, ssl, virtual-host

I have defined in `ssl.conf`

> SSLStrictSNIVHostCheck On

Now, I have defined a series of virtual hosts and I would like to define specific SSLProtocol for each one, such as

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
  ServerName      first.server.on.my.domain
  SSLProtocol    -all +TLSv1.2 +TLSv1.3
</virtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
  ServerName      second.server.on.my.domain
  SSLProtocol    -all +TLSv1.3
</virtualHost>
```

For both I use wildcard certificates for ***server.on.my.domain**.
What is happening is that (testing with `curl --tlsv1.2...`) the second host still accepts TLS 1.2! :-(

1. is it possible to do that? if yes
2. how could I do it?

I have Apache **2.4.38** and OpenSSL **1.1.1d**.

Comment: Likely to be a duplicate of https://serverfault.com/questions/637344/is-it-possible-to-set-an-sslprotocol-in-apache-for-a-single-virtualhost-poodle on Server Fault.

Comment: Not quite; there it was stated that `You can set the SSLProtocol only for the first VirtualHost in the configuration file` (and this is what is happening to me) but according to https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/HTTPD/NameBasedSSLVHostsWithSNI ```With SNI, you can have many virtual hosts sharing the same IP address and port, and each one can have its own unique certificate (and the rest of the configuration).```

Comment: Since you are using the same certificate perhaps the part that you quoted that says "unique certificate" comes into play. Have you/can you try with separate certificates?

Comment: Something like ```SSLEngine                on
      SSLCertificateKeyFile    /.../privkey.pem      SSLCertificateFile       /.../fullchain.pem       SSLProtocol              -all +TLSv1.3``` ? Yes, that is actually what I am doing... and, BTW, I just upgraded to Apache 2.4.41, the same thing! :-(

Comment: My certificate has a wildcard, it should work for both of them; actually I have modified the log line definition to add the virtual host in the log and indeed I noticed the requests are directed to the good virtual server - but overall it behaves like Apache ignores the SNI from the request...

Comment: @John75: No; it also was stated that this is only `due to an OpenSSL bug` and there is a patch available.

Comment: The OpenSSL bug has been closed on `Thu Oct 13 18:51:46 2016` - I am using OpenSSL **1.1.1d** that is supposed to have the bug fixed.